# Citing source of a theory?

Tags: citations, plagiarism

Is it required to cite the source(s) in the cited works list if you mention a known theory like for example Maslow pyramide of needs?

Comment: Are you writing a paper as a course assignment or writing a research paper for publication?

Comment: Ah yes. Good to capitalize Maslow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cite things that are "common knowledge". But this depends to a pretty big extent on the audience. If you were writing for me, you would need to cite it since this is the first time I'd be likely to see the term. If you were writing for a psychology audience it might be different (I can't judge, obviously).

However, while it may not be *required* to cite, it might (in many circumstances) be polite. If you err, then I suggest doing so on the side of over, not under, citation.

On the other hand, you are unlikely to be accused of plagiarism, specifically, if you use an unfamiliar term.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing a historical examination of a theory, you don't always have to cite the original source of an idea.  Some ideas have entered the literature to such an extent that authors may just give some key citations to major works, which may not have been the original works on the topic.  Academic papers will sometimes briefly discuss the genesis of a theory, but often they just cite some major works confirming the existence of the theory and then they get down to business.

When you have a theory that is named after a person (e.g., Maslow's hierarchy of needs) you will sometimes cite the original paper just so that your reader knows where the name comes from, but this tends to be the case only if the theory is not well known.  Many named theories are so widely known in the literature that they are commonly cited without going back to the original source; e.g., when statisticians use applied Bayesian methods we do not usually cite Thomas Bayes.